# Questions about using Swiper?

Tags: javascript, css, lightbox, swiper.js

I have a problem, my English is not very good, but I try to fully describe the problem I encountered~

I currently use swiper and lightbox2 to make carousel effects, and I still don’t know if I repeatedly watch the official documents. Where is the problem?

There are three questions in total:

1. Why does the **Swiper** arrow keys not work?
2. If you want to keep the picture at 16:9, are there other settings besides setting the width and height?
3. In addition, why is my direction? The key is always in the middle, not in the middle of the picture?

Thank you everyone for watching my question. I hope you can get help. Thank you again for your assistance.

[

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  direction: 'horizontal',
  slidesPerView: 1,
  spaceBetween: 4,
  breakpointsInverse: true,
  breakpoints: { 
    //当宽度大于等于320
    320: {
      slidesPerView: 2,
      spaceBetween: 10
    },
   //当宽度大于等于480
    480: { 
      slidesPerView: 3,
      spaceBetween: 20
    },
    //当宽度大于等于640
    640: {
      slidesPerView: 3,
      spaceBetween:24
    }
  }
})
```

```css
  .swiper-slide img{
    width: 375px;
    height: 275px;
    object-fit: cover;
  }


@media(min-width:600px){
  .swiper-slide img{
    width: 240px;
    height: 135px;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
}


img{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.11.3/js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.11.3/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/7.0.9/swiper-bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="demo">
   <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <a href="https://upload.cc/i1/2021/10/20/cO8Cbn.jpg" data-lightbox="banner1" data-title="1">
            <img src="https://upload.cc/i1/2021/10/20/cO8Cbn.jpg" alt="">
          </a>  
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
           <a href="https://upload.cc/i1/2021/10/20/1NYZ0y.jpg" data-lightbox="banner1" data-title="1">
              <img src="https://upload.cc/i1/2021/10/20/1NYZ0y.jpg" alt="">
            </a>  
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
           <a href="https://upload.cc/i1/2021/10/22/xAOuwi.jpg" data-lightbox="banner1" data-title="1">
              <img src="https://upload.cc/i1/2021/10/22/xAOuwi.jpg" alt="">
            </a>  
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- 如果需要分页器 -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    <!-- 如果需要导航按钮 -->
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
</div>
</div>
```